# Openlayers WMTS not generating correct url

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I have correctly created an openlayers map with a wmts layer which works fine in the lowest zoom levels. As soon as it hits a single digit zoom level the map stops working.

working url from old version of app:http://geodata1.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYER=luchtfoto&STYLE=&TILEMATRIXSET=nltilingschema&TILEMATRIX=09&TILEROW=244&TILECOL=235&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg

broken url from new version of app:
http://geodata1.nationaalgeoregister.nl/luchtfoto/wmts?layer=luchtfoto&style&tilematrixset=nltilingschema&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.3.0&Format=image%2Fjpeg&TileMatrix=8&TileCol=119&TileRow=121

A difference is hard to find, since it is only ONE digit. The leading zero before the single digit near the paramater "TileMatrix" is missing, and after searching the api i couldn't find a way of changing this. I tried manually creating the matrix ids but this did not mather. Does anyone have a clue as to what needs to be done to get this working?

regards Casper

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, long day, long story short had to change the MatrixId array to string with leading zero's in front of the correct numbers instead of INTs.